# Kitchen sink not running in gennymotion

Tags: android, appcelerator

New to appcelerator, i have genymotion installed and wanna laun kitchen sink inside it but i get following errors, i already checked solutions on google but nothing found:

```
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
[ERROR] :  The minimum supported SDK version must be 10 or newer, but is currently set to 8
Update the android:minSdkVersion in the tiapp.xml or custom AndroidManifest to at least 10:
```

Inside tiapp.xml i have not android:minSdkVersion and i don't found any android manifest inside the project.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At tiapp.xml of [KitchenSink](https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink/blob/stable/tiapp.xml) official repository.

You should add:

```
...
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10"/>
....
```

I hope my answer helps you ;)

Comment: Hello thank you for thé ans web,  gonna test it and ré - post result:)